# Rerendering block over selected option?

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender

I am working with ObjectPermissions. I have a selectOption

```
 options.add(new SelectOption('All', 'All'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('Create', 'Create Permission'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('Read', 'Read Permission'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('Edit', 'Edit Permission'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('Delete', 'Delete Permission'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('ModifyAll', 'Modify All Permission'));
    options.add(new SelectOption('ViewAll', 'View All Permission'));
```

for each selection, the selected columns are different. How do i rerender the block so that columns do not clash?

```
<apex:outputPanel id="All" rendered="{!renderblock['All']}">
                        <apex:pageBlockTable var="per" value="{!Permissions}">  
                            <apex:column headerValue="Profile" value="{!per.Parent.Profile.Name}" />
                            <apex:column headerValue="Object Name" value="{!per.SobjectType}"/>                         
                            <apex:column headerValue="Permission Create" value="{!per.PermissionsCreate}" />
                            <apex:column headerValue="Permission Read" value="{!per.PermissionsRead}" />
                            <apex:column headerValue="Permission Edit" value="{!per.PermissionsEdit}" />
                            <apex:column headerValue="Permission Delete" value="{!per.PermissionsDelete}" />
                            <apex:column headerValue="Permission View All" value="{!per.PermissionsViewAllRecords}" />
                            <apex:column headerValue="Permission Modify All" value="{!per.PermissionsModifyAllRecords}" />
                        </apex:pageBlockTable>
                    </apex:outputPanel>                  

                    <apex:outputPanel id="Read"  rendered="{!renderblock['Read']}">
                        <apex:pageBlockTable var="per" value="{!Permissions}" html-class="table table-hover">  
                            <apex:column headerValue="Profile" value="{!per.Parent.Profile.Name}" />
                            <apex:column headerValue="Object Name" value="{!per.SobjectType}"/>         
                            <apex:column headerValue="Permission Read" value="{!per.PermissionsRead}" />
                        </apex:pageBlockTable>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
```

In above code, when i make `{!renderblock['Read']}` map value true, vf page throws error

Comment: Please share your markup if you would like any help fixing your markup.

Comment: What error is being thrown?

Comment: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: ObjectPermissions.PermissionsRead

Comment: Error denotes that the query you used to fetch `Permissions` does not contains `PermissionsRead` field in your SOQL.